# Cmd locking after running SHH

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Ok so i am making a custom minecraft server bat here is the code

```
color a
@echo off
title Minecraft Server CONSOLE
prompt [server]:
cls

:choice
set /P a=Start Sever[Yes/No]?
if /I "%a%" EQU "Yes" goto :start
if /I "%a%" EQU "No" goto :stop
goto :choice

:start
**cmd.exe /c start /min ssh -R WolfCraft.Serveo.net:11111:localhost:25565 
serveo.net
cls
echo loading server...
java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar server.jar nogui
cls

:choice
set /P a=do you want to restart[Yes/No]?
if /I "%a%" EQU "Yes" goto :restart
if /I "%a%" EQU "No" goto :stop


:restart
cls
echo server will restart
TIMEOUT /T 3
cls
goto :start

:stop
taskkill /fi "Windowtitle eq OpenSSH SSH client*" /im cmd.exe 
cls
echo closing server
TIMEOUT /T 3
exit
```

I put 2 stars on what needs to be edited.
The problem is as you can see by the code i am running this command

```
ssh -R WolfCraft.Serveo.net:11111:localhost:25565 serveo.net
```

In a seperate window because of when i just put the command it launched the tcp redirect but it wont let the console do anymore commands and is stuck in shh. I want shh.exe and the java minecraft server.jar to work both in 1 cmd

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to spawn a separate Window for CMD to run the code in that line you need to use Start to call command instead of command to call start.

ie:

```
start /min "OpenSSH SSH client" "cmd.exe /c ssh -R WolfCraft.Serveo.net:11111:localhost:25565 serveo.net"
```

This assumes that SSH is found on the path in Windows though, if it is NOT then you need to put the full file path:

```
start /min "OpenSSH SSH client" /D "C:\Path\to\ssh\folder\" "cmd.exe /c ssh -R WolfCraft.Serveo.net:11111:localhost:25565 serveo.net"
```

Comment: I have it set to a different window now.. I want to set them both in window so it will run the shh.exe windows client and the java.jar in 1 window

Comment: @AndrewW Both the code you used and the way the script is set up, seem to indicate that you expected the SSH service to be spawned as a separate process (IE in its own CMD instance -- or a separate window, as you later look for that window title and attempt to kill it.).  Why are you doing all that if you want CMD to wait until the JAVA process you spawn completes?

Comment: @AndrewW What are you attempting to accomplish with this code exactly?   If you want to run commands in the Java console from a script that is not directly possible unless the Java application you are running is written to allow stdin piped from the command line to it on run, in which case it woudl have to be `ECHO`ed and piped `|` to it, or it would have to be in a separate file and then read from that file into the command.  However, the script can not continue on until the Java app finishes it's processing and terminates unless this is done in a separate CMD instance as done by using Start.

Comment: @AndrewW - On re-read, it seems like you want to log into a remote server and have it run the Java App?  In this case, you will need to connect to the remote server (`SSH`) using `PLINK` which is scriptable and execute the command to start the Server remotely on that system, then end the `SSH` session.  If you later want to stop that process on the remote server you will need to log into it over SSH again and run some command to kill the Minecraft server.  Alternately you can also restart Minecraft using the `MinecraftClient.exe` with the Scripting plugin

Comment: okay so when it lunched i type yes and then it will start the java in the same window and lunch an external shh cmd then when i type stop it stops the java file and kills the shh cmd and asks if i want to restart. Pretty straight forward and it works well but what i want to do is run the shh and the java in one cmd not 2 so that say i collapse the cmd in task manager it will show the server.jar and the shh.exe (shh service) in the same cmd and not 2 the problem i have with just doing lunch is if the java service is running the cmd will not allow shh to run and viceversa